# Digispark 5V Output Problem

Tags: arduino

I've got a Digispark, a Keyboard and a USB Type A Female Breakout.

I've got the following diagram and I've wired up everything as shown in the image: [image: Diagram]

However, when I plug in the keyboard to the USB Breakout and the Digispark to the computer, the keyboard's LED does not turn on (it's supposed to be turned on 24/7 by default).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What software are you running on the Digispark?

Comment: Does it matter? Since the GND and 5V are supposed to be outputting power by default.

Any specific code you'd suggest I upload to see if the error is software-side?

Comment: USB devices typically require an active USB host to start up.

Comment: What do you mean by that and how do I fix it?

Comment: Er, "active" means that software on both devices must communicate with each other. As far as I know, the Digispark is too slow for that.

Comment: But I'm only providing power to my keyboard. I don't expect to press keys and the digispark will read those actions etc.
It's like I plug the keyboard directly into a usb brick plug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64947/discussion-between-coto-and-cl).

Answer (score 1):

The USB specification defines many states that a USB device can be in, depending on how the host interacts with it. But when there is no activity on the bus (on the D+/D− data lines), the device must go into the "suspended" state to save power:

[image: USB states]

The only state in which a device is allowed to draw much power is "configured".
So unless you manage to communicate with the keyboard (which requires implementing the electrical USB protocol, and a huge USB software stack), the keyboard will not power up.

Comment: By the way, the digispark, while it has enough resources to work as a rudimental USB device, it has no enough resources to work both as a host (kb side) AND a device (pc side), especially at the same time.